# Does $x'' = x^3$ have an analytical solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I encountered this differential equation $x'' = x^3$ during one of my work and couldn't find an analytical solution to the above. I've used numerical methods to solve the equation in the end.

I was just wondering if there is any way to find an analytical solution or show that an elementary solution doesn't exist.

WolframAlpha expresses the answer with Jacobi theta functions, and I was wondering if that's the only way to express the answer.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid integrals of the form $$\int\,\frac{\text{d}u}{\sqrt{u^4\pm1}}\,.$$  So, if you want some elementary functions, then you are out of luck.

Comment: What's wrong with Jacobi theta functions? They are analytic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use $${\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}}=-\frac{\dfrac{d^2t}{dx^2}}{\left(\dfrac{dt}{dx}\right)^3}$$ the equation becomes 
$$t''+(t')^3 x^3=0$$ Let $t'=y$ to get $$y'+y^3x^3=0$$ Now $y=\frac 1 {\sqrt z}$ to get
$$z'=2x^3 \implies z=c_1+\frac{x^4}{2}\implies  y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{c_1+\frac{x^4}{2}}}$$ and finally
$$t+c_2=\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{c_1+\frac{x^4}{2}}}$$ leading to elliptic integrals.

I suppose that back to $x$, we should get some Jacobi elliptic function.